# Avoid re-display of menu using MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, menu

My team is creating an MVC4 application which has an upper menu structure that contains menu items specific for the currently logged-in user, and displays the content for the selected menu item below. The menus are displayed in a partial view "_MainMenu" and the MainMenuController Index action is responsible for getting the menu data from the database and returning the menu partial view. The main layout "_Layout" renders the menu by calling @Html.Action("Index", "MainMenu").

We want to avoid hitting the database to get the menu structure data every time the page is refreshed, and we also ideally want to avoid any visible reload of the menu structure when a different menu item is selected.

I've been looking into AJAX, and I've implemented something where selecting a new menu item will load the content for that item below the menu by replacing a div with ID="mainContent" with the content as a partial view (this div lives on the loaded view "MainContent"). In this way, the menu is never re-loaded and the page never refreshes completely (only the different partial content views are swapped in and out as different menu items are selected).

This solution works, but I'm not sure if it's really best practice, or if there's a better solution involving caching. One of the problems with the AJAX solution is the URL never changes from "http://MySite/MainContent". This means that clicking the Back button on the browser doesn't work as expected, and also hitting F5 to refresh the browser page loses the currently displayed page. The refresh issue can probably be resolved by remembering the selected menu item, but I'm still not convinced this isthe way AJAX was intended to be used.

Can someone please tell me if they think caching would be a better solution for this scenario based on their experience.

Answer (score 0):

If the user's menu items are not likely to change, then you could use a simple static Dictionary (the long is the user id) to cache the data in the backend, and refresh it periodically.

Generally, if you do any caching you have to make sure the cached data gets refreshed when underlying data is updated. Therefore it's only simple and safe if you have only one app accessing your DB. If there are multiple apps, then you'll have to add a mechanism to keep the cache in sync.

In project I'm working on we've stored User-Role-Module entities and relationships in DB, and bound module permissions to roles rather than users. Since role permissions aren't likely to change, they're safe to cache.